# Disabling Language Bar on Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012

I need to disable the language bar on Windows Server 2012R2 for some reason and what I've found online does not seem to solve it for me. I've started looking at Win8 solutions to this thinking that it will use the same settings on Server 2012 but so far I can't do it.

Here's a list of things I've found and tried:

- http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5904-language-bar-turn-off-windows-8-a.html (number 7, the option is unchecked but I still see the bar)
- [Remove the Language Bar from the taskbar (WinXP)](https://serverfault.com/questions/6255/remove-the-language-bar-from-the-taskbar-winxp) (this doesn't work, I get an 0x80004005 error, both on win8 and Server 2012 on different domain, one is brand new, so I corssed it out)
- http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX113114 (just did not work, it added the keys successfully but I still see the bar)

And a couple more registry/GPO settings I can't remember at this point. Has anybody done this before? I'd appreciate if anybody can at least try one of the options I listed and let me know if it worked for them so I can start troubleshooting.

Comment: ...Why?  What did the language bar ever do to you?  Did you try #6 on your first link and set the language bar to "Hidden"?

Comment: I hate to do this, but it is a request from above my paygrade. I did number 6, it did not work on Server 2012. It either selects one type of language bar or the other, content is the same, I want both  gone, completely, even hidden just makes it pop up as a floating window.

Comment: Yea, there are way too many days I wish the paygrades were flipped.  When it switches to the floating window and you close it, does it come back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Windows Server 2012 R2 doesn't show a language bar, it shows an indicator in the tray area:

[image]

You change between input languages by pressing WIN+Spacebar. If you want to get rid of the indicator do the following:

- Right click on the task bar, choose Properties.
- On the `Taskbar` tab click `Customize...`
- Click the `Turn system icons on or off` link.
- Switch `Input Indicator` to Off:

[image]

Comment: Thank's, I shouldn't have missed this. Any idea what GPO setting or registry entry this is tied to?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
1- Check the box before "Control Panel - Language - Advanced settings - Use the desktop language bar when it's available";
2- Click the link below - "Change language bar hot keys", then select the "language bar" tab, choose "Hidden".
```

Comment: Yes, Hidden makes it a "floating" one for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this "Input Indicator" by setting a Group Policy Preference GPP (sorry for the german language entry, but you figure it out for sure):

Struktur: HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Schlüsselpfad: Control Panel\Desktop

Name: UserPreferencesMask

Werttyp: REG_BINARY

Wertdaten: 9012038010010000

Answer (score 0):

To disable language bar on Windows Server 2012 R2 just add the following registry entry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Citrix\wfshell\TWI

REG_DWORD=SeamlessFlags

Value=0x00040000 (Hex) or 262144 (decimal)
```

It's also working on Citrix XenApp 7.11