# Turn system icons off with GPO or Registry

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-registry, windows

I need to turn off "Input Indicator" on the taskbar with  a GPO or a Registry setting (which will turn into a GPO). It took me quite a while to figure out how to do it in Control Panel, now I have to do the same thing on GPO.

Here's the reference: [Disabling Language Bar on Server 2012 R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/661389/disabling-language-bar-on-server-2012-r2)

Comment: Do you want to remove it or do you want to hide it? If you want to hide it there's a User Configuration setting for "Hide the notification area". Note that this will hide all of the icons in the notification area.

Comment: I don't want to hide them all. And that option I believe does not hide the keyboard input.

Comment: -1 for the second question, because google gives 75 million results for 'compare registry'

Comment: Agreed. I found it after 5 second.But it does not help me.